# ¿Es posible aceptar dos respuestas​ como correctas?

Tags: soporte, respuesta-aceptada

¿Es posible en Stack Overflow en español y  Stack Overflow en inglés aceptar dos respuestas como correctas​?

Porque hace poco hice una pregunta sobre jQuery, pero las dos son correctas y me ayudaron.

Comment: Me temo que no es posible, cualquier sitio de la red de Stack Exchange solo permite tener una respuesta válida por cada pregunta realizada.

Comment: Que mala onda :( pero las dos respuesta son correctas.

Comment: Por supuesto que sí que se puede. Escribe una nueva respuesta que contenga las dos respuestas que quieres aceptar y acepta esa nueva respuesta. Harina de otro costal es que hacer esto sea útil. Si tu nueva respuesta se limita a copiar y pegar las otras dos entonces es una repetición que no aporta nada nuevo. Si fusiona las dos preguntas, eliminando elementos repetidos, juntando las virtudes de ambas y ofreciendo un resultado que es mejor que la suma de sus partes entonces sí que podría valer la pena.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

Sólo una puede ser aceptada como correcta. Deberías elegir la que creas que mejor responde a tu pregunta, pensando en qué fue útil para tu caso y que podría ser útil para futuros lectores.

Esto es parte del modelo de Stack Overflow, y una de las características que contribuyen al éxito. El hecho de que dudes entre aceptar dos respuestas diferentes suele ser un indicador de que la pregunta no estaba bien enfocada o era un poco amplia. Las preguntas deberían ser concretas y sobre un punto específico, buscando una única respuesta válida.

Además, podrías:

- Votar +1 a todas las respuestas que te fueron útiles.
- Comentar debajo de la pregunta/respuesta en caso de que creas conveniente guiar a futuros lectores a leer otra respuesta.
- Ofrecer [recompensas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) a las respuestas en caso de que lo consideres pertinente.

Comment: ¿y en alguna comunidad de StackExchange, o solo en StackOverflow?

Comment: @ArtEze es lo mismo para cualquier comunidad de Stack Exchange. En esa frase me refería a Stack Overflow como compañía, y su modelo.